# How do I fix "<No main class found>"?

Tags: java, netbeans, program-entry-point

I am trying to run some Java code in NetBeans and it keeps telling me that there is no main class. I have looked at other similar questions but they don't help in fixing my particular problem.

Even when I add the main loop it still tells me there is no main class. The purpose of this code is to create a class called VolcanoRobot which can be used in another program, or I could add the `public static void main(String args[])` and just run this code.

Trying both methods the compiler still has this same issue. Here is the code I have for using the class:

```
class VolcanoApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args ){
     VolcanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
     dante.status = "exploring";
     dante.speed = 2;
     dante.temperature = 510;

     dante.showAttributes();
     System.out.println("Increasing speed to 3.");
     dante.speed = 3;
     dante.showAttributes();
     System.out.println("Changing temperature to 670.");
     dante.temperature = 670;
     dante.showAttributes();
     System.out.println("Checking the temparature");
     dante.checkTemperature();
     dante.showAttributes();


}}
```

Creation of VolcanoRobot:

```
    class  VolcanoRobot {
        String status;
        int speed;
        float temperature;

        void checkTemperature() {
            if (temperature > 600) {
                status = "returning home";
                speed = 5;
            }
        }

        void showAttributes() {
            System.out.println("Status: " + status);
            System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
            System.out.println("Temperature: " + temperature);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have other classes or this is all your code? - In fact you need to have a public class containing a main method. If you do not have any then this is the problem.

Comment: How are you running your project?

Comment: I am running it using NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a main class that calls your VolcanoRobot like this:

```
public class MyMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VolcanoRobot bot = new VolcanoRobot();
        bot.showAttributes();
        bot.checkTemperature();
        bot.showAttributes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't contain `static void main(String[] args)`. A main-class is the class that java uses as entrypoint for the program. Or to be more specific, `public static void main(String[] args)` is the entrypoint. Or respectively the method that is called to start the program. Since this code doesn't contain a `main` method, java doesn't know where to start the program and complains about that problem.

This is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN) in the oracle java-tutorial